# FQL Limit clause showing greater number of results than it should?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I have a simple query to show a given users photos:

```
SELECT pid FROM photo_tag WHERE subject in "12345" LIMIT 400,500
```

It returns 500 results... shouldn't it return 100?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Your query is asking for 500 records starting with record 401.

To return the records 400-500 your query should read

```
SELECT pid FROM photo_tag WHERE subject in "12345" LIMIT 400, 100
```